# Mysql + Visual Studio 2012 "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider"

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

Mysql + Visual Studio 2012

```
"Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider"
```

Hello everyone I would like to ask for help about this error i am experiencing. I used Visual Studio 2012 with `entity framework 5` and the `mysql` I downloaded through this link http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html. In the project I added the ADO.NET Entity Data Model with 'generate from database' which is the MySql with port 3307 (3306 used by other). I tested the connection and it says 'Test Connection Succeded'. So I started coding with insert query to the database. When I test to run, it hunged up and says

```
"Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider".
```

Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is simply to install the MySQL.Data and MySQL.Data.Entities packages via NuGet. Just using the MySQL for Windows installer won't add the necessary DLL's and project references you need, but NuGet will do that for you automatically.

Here's a link... use the top 2 packages: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mysql

Comment: @Wao are those packages just installed on something like your domain model / data access layer and not the layer that may be running the app (like a web project)?  You'll need them on the project actually doing the execution as well.

Comment: I am actually a beginner for this. I do not know. I just installed both via References(right click) -> Manage Nuget Packages -> Search for the two dll's -> then install both. That's it. I just made that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way through code without app.config: (don't forget to set the right MySql.Data version in this code)

```
  public class MySqlDbConfiguration: DbConfiguration 
{
    public MySqlDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MySqlConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySqlProviderServices());
        RegisterFactoryIfRequired();
    }

    private static void RegisterFactoryIfRequired()
    {
        string dataProvider = @"MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
        string dataProviderDescription = @".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL";
        string dataProviderName = @"MySQL Data Provider";
        string dataProviderType =
            @"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d";

        bool addProvider = true;
        var dataSet = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as DataSet;
        foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if ((row["InvariantName"] as string) == dataProvider)
            {
                // it is already in the config, no need to add.
                addProvider = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (addProvider)
            dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dataProviderName, dataProviderDescription, dataProvider, dataProviderType);

        // test it
        var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
    }

}
```